# What is the benefit of artificially padding messages?

Tags: cbc, padding, ecb, cfb

For ECB, CBC, and CFB, padding is required when the plaintext does not fill out a complete multiple of the block size. However, I have heard that is good practice to pad all messages, even if the plaintext does fill out a complete multiple of the block size. What benefit does doing such a thing have? Does it increase security in any way?

Comment: Where did you hear this? In some cases there may be a minor benefit to hiding some information about a message's length, you may be misinterpreting what you've read: If you want to allow messages that aren't a multiple of the block size, then padding is *required* even for a message that *is* a multiple of the block size. Otherwise, how can you tell a padded message apart from a plaintext that happens to end in a sequence of bytes that is also valid padding?

Comment: CFB doesn't require padding.

Comment: Related question: [Why can the last block contain a full block of padding in CBC Encryption?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24130/why-can-the-last-block-contain-a-full-block-of-padding-in-cbc-encryption)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, while theoretically CFB does not require padding, [NIST requires that you use padding with it](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2747/13625)... Anyway, I think this is simply dupe of the question you linked.